# How can i join three table result into one result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following three result from the same table with different where statement

```
  SELECT count(*) as LONG_TERM_LEASE_2017_Apirl
  FROM drivenow.rent 
  where (rentalterm="Both" OR rentalterm="Long") AND (created_at BETWEEN '2017-04-01' AND '2017-04-30');

SELECT count(*) as LONG_TERM_LEASE_2017_May 
FROM drivenow.rent 
where (rentalterm="Both" OR rentalterm="Long") AND (created_at BETWEEN '2017-05-01' AND '2017-05-30');

SELECT count(*) as LONG_TERM_LEASE_2017_June
FROM drivenow.rent
WHERE (rentalterm="both" OR  rentalterm="Long" )AND (created_at BETWEEN '2017-06-01' AND '2017-06-30');
```

I want to show something like this in my SQL result side by side

```
LONG_TERM_LEASE_2017_Apirl|LONG_TERM_LEASE_2017_May|LONG_TERM_LEASE_2017_June
```

How can i achieve this? Sorry i am beginner in programming.

Comment: See [self join](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-self-join/)

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `cross join` those three Selects, but in fact you need only a single Select using *conditional aggregation*:

```
 SELECT
    count(case when created_at BETWEEN '2017-04-01' AND '2017-04-30' then 1 end) as LONG_TERM_LEASE_2017_Apirl,
    count(case when created_at BETWEEN '2017-05-01' AND '2017-05-30' then 1 end) as LONG_TERM_LEASE_2017_May,
    count(case when created_at BETWEEN '2017-06-01' AND '2017-06-30' then 1 end) as LONG_TERM_LEASE_2017_June
  FROM drivenow.rent 
  where (rentalterm="Both" OR rentalterm="Long") 
    AND (created_at BETWEEN '2017-04-01' AND '2017-06-30' );
```

The `1`returned by the case is just a dummy value for counting.
Instead of `count` you can also use a sum like this:

```
sum(case when created_at BETWEEN '2017-04-01' AND '2017-04-30' then 1 else 0 end)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
COUNT(CASE WHEN (rentalterm="Both" OR rentalterm="Long") AND (created_at BETWEEN '2017-04-01' AND '2017-04-30') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as LONG_TERM_LEASE_2017_Apirl,
COUNT(CASE WHEN (rentalterm="Both" OR rentalterm="Long") AND (created_at BETWEEN '2017-05-01' AND '2017-05-30'); then 1 ELSE NULL END) as LONG_TERM_LEASE_2017_May ,
COUNT(CASE WHEN (rentalterm="both" OR  rentalterm="Long" )AND (created_at BETWEEN '2017-06-01' AND '2017-06-30') then 1 ELSE NULL END) as LONG_TERM_LEASE_2017_June
from drivenow.rent ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
select
SUM(case when (rentalterm="Both" OR rentalterm="Long") AND (created_at BETWEEN '2017-04-01' AND '2017-04-30') then 1 else 0) as LONG_TERM_LEASE_2017_Apirl,
SUM(case when (rentalterm="Both" OR rentalterm="Long") AND (created_at BETWEEN '2017-05-01' AND '2017-05-30') then 1 else 0) as LONG_TERM_LEASE_2017_May,
SUM(case when (rentalterm="both" OR  rentalterm="Long" )AND (created_at BETWEEN '2017-06-01' AND '2017-06-30') then 1 else 0) as LONG_TERM_LEASE_2017_June
FROM drivenow.rent 
WHERE(rentalterm="Both" OR rentalterm="Long") AND (created_at BETWEEN '2017-04-01' AND '2017-06-30') then 1 else 0)
```